# need help to solve Objective-c simple program output

Tags: objective-c

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface engine : NSObject

@end




#import "engine.h"

@implementation engine

-(NSString *)discription{
    return (@"I am an engine");
}
@end



#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface tire : NSObject

@end



#import "tire.h"

@implementation tire
-(NSString *)description{
    return (@"I am a tire, I last for a while");
}
@end




#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "tire.h"
#import "engine.h"
@interface car : NSObject{
    engine *eng;
    tire *tir[4];
}
-(void)print;
@end




#import "car.h"

@implementation car

-(id)init{
    if(self ==[super init]){
        eng=[engine new];
        tir[0]=[tire new];
        tir[1]=[tire new];
        tir[2]=[tire new];
        tir[3]=[tire new];

    }
    return (self); 
}
-(void)print{
    NSLog(@"%@",eng);
    NSLog(@"%@",tir[0]);
    NSLog(@"%@",tir[1]);
    NSLog(@"%@",tir[2]);
    NSLog(@"%@",tir[3]);
}

@end









#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "car.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    car *ca;
    ca=[car new];
    [ca print];
    return (0);

}
```

//output result when run the program at Xcode:

//    2012-12-27 00:55:31.241 CarProject[9341:f803] engine: 0x686d990

//    2012-12-27 00:55:31.244 CarProject[9341:f803] I am a tire, I last for a while

//    2012-12-27 00:55:31.245 CarProject[9341:f803] I am a tire, I last for a while

//    2012-12-27 00:55:31.246 CarProject[9341:f803] I am a tire, I last for a while

//    2012-12-27 00:55:31.246 CarProject[9341:f803] I am a tire, I last for a while

//    so the engine can't properly output the string. i need help on this. thank you.

Comment: What's your question? What's your expected output? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: That is some seriously non-standard Objective-C you got there (in the context of the Foundation).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have misspelled the name of the description method of the `Engine` class: it should be `description`, not `discription`.

Comment: +1 nice catch - bad question but nice catch